# How to cross-browser remove a part of a string with random length and __xyz__ boundary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, internet-explorer, split

I have a form which has a dynamic number for fields with field names iterating like this:

```
 fieldA__1__
 fieldA__2__
 fieldA__3__
```

In my form handler I have response messages for all incoming errors, however, I have only a single response for `fieldA`, so my error handler will not have a response if the server tells me `field__123__` is wrong.

I tried to fix this splitting the returned field like so:

```
// returnField = "fieldA__1__";
lookupField = returnfield.split("__")[0]
```

which I hoped would always give me the fieldname I'm looking for, because the split should always return the field I'm looking for.

```
fieldA      >  fieldA
fieldA__1__ >  fieldA
```

However, this seems to break in IE... (of course).

**Question:**
What is a cross-browser safe way to split strings and return the first element of the split string?

Thanks!

Comment: `.split()` is supported in IE. What is the error you get?

Comment: I'm trying to track it down. I changed from using `returnfield` only to `returnfield.split("__")[0]` which seemed to have broken something. Will re-post once I have it